# WiFi doesn't work. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: internet, connection

I started using Ubuntu 22.04 in my Dell InspironN7110 six months ago, and since this I have been having problems with the internet. While I'm using the laptop I always have the internet symbol activated, but when I try to use the browser or any other app which needs wifi, the speed is very slowly and it randomly disconnects. It doesn't happen in any other device, I didn't have this kind of problems in my Del before install Ubuntu (when I was using windows 10)

Comment: Doubt I can help, but this needs more info. What have you done to try to figure out what the issue is? What have you done to try to fix it? Info about the Wi-Fi card may also help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)